# The Buddha And The Beggar Story

Tags: eightfold-path

I was watching this YouTube Video about the [The Buddha And The Beggar](https://youtu.be/VOh6xUIIs3w)

My question as mentioned in the comment of that video is `why is that the beggar can have only 8 items in the possessions and what are those 8 items?`

One of the commentator mentioned that `the story in thai its  8/100 (eight-one-hundred). It,s not 8 items` and ﻿the other mentioned that it has something to do with the `The Eightfold Path`. I have a fair understanding of `The Noble Eightfold Path` but I do not understand it's relation to my original question.

Can anyone shed more light here? What am I missing here? If there is no relation then what is the answer to my original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably the "[8 requisites](http://www.buddhisma2z.com/content.php?id=340)" of a monk, i.e. the 8 items that a monk is allowed and needs: 3 robes, an alms bowl, a waistband, a razor, a sewing kit and a water strainer.

Comment: Nice! That makes sense!